# Deixar bullets centralizado e setas de navegação a direita e esquerda em slider

Tags: jquery, css

Estou tentado sem sucesso deixar as bullets de navegação centralizadas e as setas de navegação ao lado direito e esquerdo do slider, por mais que altera as configurações do css não obtenho sucesso.

O site é esse: [Site em desenvolvimento](http://moveissaobento.com.br/msb/)

Para as setas, tenho isso:

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    background-image: url(../images/slider/arrows.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -999em;
}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev.flex-disabled {
    background-position: 10px 7px;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next, .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next.flex-disabled {
    background-position: -17px 7px;
}
```

E para as bullets isso:

```
.flex-control-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
    margin-left: 8px;
    float: left;
}
.flex-control-nav li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-paging a {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -999em;
}
.flex-control-paging a:hover {
    background-color: #999;
}
.flex-control-paging a.flex-active {
    cursor: default;
}
```

No caso dos bullets tentei alterar isso:

```
flex-control-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 6%;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Mas como disse, sem sucesso.

Comment: Esse site na sua pergunta é um exemplo do que você quer ou é o seu site?

Comment: Olá @André Ribeiro, esse site é o que estou desenvolvendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte:

Aqui os bullets são centralizados ajustando as propriedades `left` e `right` para `0` e `margin` para `0 auto`. Usando esse método a largura precisa ser fixa.

```
.flex-control-nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70px;
    bottom: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Nessa parte o ideal seria separar as setas no HTML e ajustar o css de acordo. O código abaixo vai funcionar com a versão atual setando o `ul` pra 100% de largura e os `li` com `position: absolute` um de cada lado.

```
ul.flex-direction-nav {
    width: 100%;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li:first-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li:last-of-type {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Olá @Andre Ribeiro, sua ajuda foi primordial, agradeço muito a atenção e a colaboração, ficou excelente.